# Create a view to display last browsed content

Tags: views, nodes

I want to create a view to display last browsed content by the user. My site has a lot of content and I want to create a view, either a page or a block, to show the last browsed content by the user. That view should show the last browsed content first followed by rest. Say for example, content A was browsed 10 seconds ago, content B 10 minutes ago and content C was 1 hour ago, then the view should list them in the order: A    B   C.

Thanks

Comment: I thought of using the Tracker module for doing so but when i create the view i do not find any Sort Criteria relating to this. Is there any other module or does it require some custom module creation

Comment: I am thinking of using the Radioactivity module...however there are two sorting criteria available as:                     1.radioactivity_energy
2.radioactivity_timestamp.  I think i should use timestamp for this as i do not want the most popular contents rather i want the last visited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to do so using the sort criteria timestamp by the [Radioactivity](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module.

> This module provides a field type which can be used as a hotness metric or a regular view counter for entities and for much much more. In essense, entities receiving attention (views or actions defined by Rules) are heated while inactive ones slowly cool down.

Comment: thanks for the edit..still new at this...will follow it from next time onwards...thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should be using the core tracker module. This allows you to keep track of your last visited pages.

Comment: i though so...but what sort criteria should i add...i am unable to find any criteria which says something about this